# External form login for a Sharepoint 2010 FBA system

Tags: php, authentication, sharepoint-2010, fba

We have a MOSS 2010 box running some web apps with a FBA system and a custom login on our designed home page. The web app is on port 85 and the port 80 holds a home page with some static content as well as the login box.

I'm trying to replace the content management by some other solution since SharePoint is a bit of an overkill for our actual needs. This means replacing the current embedded SP login form by a simple one like this:

```
<form action="myAuthPage.aspx" method="POST">
  <input...>
</form>
```

As i've been searching through the net, nothing relevant appeared. Is this kind of method possible and how can it be implemented?

Comment: @Marek Grzenkowicz Sorry, i'll try to be more precise. There's currently 2 applications : 1 SharepPoint CMS on :80 and another restricted access app on :85.The CMS is too much of a hassle to deal with on a daily use, so we decided to switch to Wordpress for the 6 pages we're managing. The SP CMS has a login form that redirects to :85 app on success. I want to have a somewhat or same behavior for upcoming wordpress replacement.

Comment: I guess it is possible, but it won't be easy - you need to: (1) create a login form in Wordpress, (2) access SharePoint authentication Web service from PHP code, (3) call appropriate method and  receive the result, (4) redirect the user if authentication is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the solution revolves around the /_vti_bin/Authentication.asmx web service. It is indeed a bit heavy.

I found some snippet that one could find useful:

http://davidsit.wordpress.com/2010/02/23/reading-a-sharepoint-list-with-php/